What information is contained in the trace file in the .next directory of a Next.js project?
I am working on a Next.js project, and I have encountered an issue where the build process is extremely slow, taking almost an hour to complete. While investigating the potential causes, I came across a file named trace in the .next directory.
Could someone please explain what information is contained in this trace file? Additionally, is it possible to find clues within this file that could help me understand why my build process is so slow?
Here is what I have found so far:

The trace file contains various information in JSON format.
It includes fields like timestamp and duration, which seem to indicate the time taken for certain tasks to complete.

Here is some additional context that might be helpful:

I am using Next.js version 14.2.3.
My project includes TailwindCSS 3.4.1, Zustand 4.5.2, Storybook 8.1.3.


This should be answered.

I recommend increasing the resources (both memory and CPUs). Nextjs will allocate new workers if resources are available and do parallel building per dynamic segment
